# Displaying single item in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a hard time to get over this. Try to display a a single item by ID from database. I set the controller and route, but couldn't make it. Getting error or getting no data by the changes that I make on my show.blade

This is my whole controller:

```
public function welcome()
{

    $estates = array();//here

    $data['estates'] = $estates;
    return view('welcome', $data);

}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;

    $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
        ->where("building_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
        ->orWhere("address", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
        ->orWhere("company_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
        ->orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
        ->orderBy('price')->paginate(10);

    return view("search", compact('estates', 'q'));
}


public function show(allestates $allestates)
{
    $estates = allestates::where('id', $allestates->id)->first();

    //dd($estates);

    if($estates){
        return view('pages.show', ['estates' => $estates]);
    }else{
        return 'no records found';
    }
}
```

Show function must be the problem, but what is the problem I couldn't figure it out.

This is the route:

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@welcome");

Route::any("/search", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');

Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');
```

And this is the show.blade.

```
<tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>{{$estates->building_name}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

An this is the main.blade:

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)
        <tr class="even">
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->company_name, $limit = 20)}}</td>

            <td><a href="/pages/{{$estate->id}}">{{str_limit($estate->building_name, $limit = 20)}}</a></td>

            <td>{{str_limit($estate->address, $limit = 22)}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->price, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td class="price-hidden">{{$estate->old_price}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->extend, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->rooms, $limit = 20)}}</td>
            <td>{{str_limit($estate->entry, $limit = 20)}}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

ID returning null. but there is ID!

Comment: You are getting property of a element which is not a object. Try to access like array or
Try to dump the variable and print the output here

Comment: maybe `allestates::where('id', $allestates->id)->first()` returns null, maybe the id does not exists in the databse.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan that couldn't be 6 of ID in the base.

Comment: @RajeshPaudel how can I try to access it like array?

Comment: then the best thing is first check what is `$estates` looks like. `dd($estates);` this will dump the variable. then take a look for yourself, and post the output in the Question.

Comment: The common way is to use ->toArray() on the eloquent query. Then you can check if it's empty or not and show depending on result

Comment: @TharakaDilshan returns null, I don't know why. here is the database. https://imgur.com/a/rGHaecO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because laravel didn't find any record matching your query.

try using `findOrFail` in querying single record. this would return an error if no record is found.

```
$estates = allestates::findOrFail($id);
```

another way is to check wether the query is successful:

```
public function show($id)
{

   $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();
   if($estates){
      return view('pages.show', ['estates' => $estates]);
   }else{
      return 'no records found';
   }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

the `$id` paramater inside `public function show($id)` uses the `{id}` parameter in your route `Route::get('pages/{id}', 'PagesController@show');`

laravel will search the database based on the `id` you place in `yoursite.com/pages/{id}`

Comment: the first one I already tried getting 404, and the second one it returns "there is no record."　but how can it be possible I don't know. record is here: https://imgur.com/a/rGHaecO Maybe something is problem on my route?

Comment: it returned 404 since there is no record. try returning `$allestates->id` so you can see what `id` you are trying to retrieve. add `return $allestates->id;` on the 1st line  inside your `show` function.

Comment: tried this: `public function show(allestates $allestates)
    {
       return $allestates->id;
    }` but blank page returns.

Comment: try returning `$allestates` only. when it shows another blank page, it means you are not passing any data to your controller. can you show me your `route` and your `blade` in triggering the `show` function?

Comment: I updated the question with all the data, view blades, controller and the routes...

Comment: Also i can return allestates(with foreach) with no problem in on main.blade. The problem starts, when I try to return data separetly.

Comment: no problem, I've also added an explanation for you to understand why the code works.